# How to resolve when UITableview is double open on same page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I have 2 `UITableView`. On first `UITableView` make for search and select cell. After selected cell from UITableView1. It's will show blank data of UITableView2 and show new UITableView2 again with data.
I'm sorry for my bad english language.
I can speak english a little bit.
If you don't understand my question.
Please follow to see pictures below here.

1. First UITableView: (Click button for go to second UITableView.)
2. After click button. UITableView2 show blank data.
3. And auto show new UITableView2 with data again.

[image]

**UITableView1**

```
 @interface SearchByContainerDetailViewController ()
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewWhereHoseList;

    @end

    @implementation SearchByContainerDetailViewController
    @synthesize labelName,strName,txResult,strResult,labelStatus;

    NSString *selectedWhereHouse;
GlobalVariable *gloablOnWherehouse;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    labelName.text = strName;
    //txResult.text = strResult;
    labelStatus.text = @"NULL";

    gloablOnWherehouse = [GlobalVariable sharedInstance];
    gloablOnWherehouse.arTableDataSelectedWhereHouse = [[NSArray alloc] init];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return (gloablOnWherehouse.arTableDataSelected)?[gloablOnWherehouse.arTableDataSelected count]:1;

}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[gloablOnWherehouse.arTableDataSelected count]);
    return (gloablOnWherehouse.arTableDataSelected)?[gloablOnWherehouse.arTableDataSelected count]:1;
}





- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SearchByContainerDetailViewCell";
    SearchByContainerDetailViewCell *cell = [self.tableViewWhereHoseList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchByContainerDetailViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    } else {

        if (gloablOnWherehouse.arTableDataSelected) {
            NSMutableArray *myMutbleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [myMutbleArray addObject:gloablOnWherehouse.arTableDataSelected];

            if (myMutbleArray) {
                NSDictionary *myDic = [gloablOnWherehouse.arTableDataSelected objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                NSDictionary *cont = [myDic objectForKey:@"DataList_SPI_Detail"];
                NSString *date = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"date"]];
                NSString *qty = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"qty"]];
                NSString *stock = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"stock"]];
                NSString *ord = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"ord"]];
                NSString *custmr = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"custmr"]];
                NSString *remarks = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"remarks"]];
                NSString *invoice = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"invoice"]];
                NSString *due = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"due"]];
                NSString *lot = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"lot"]];
                NSString *gap = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"gap"]];

                [cell setDate:date setQty:qty setStock:stock setOrd:ord  setCustmr:custmr setRemarks:remarks setInvoice:invoice setDue:due setLot:lot setGap:gap];


            }
        }
    }
    return cell;

}



- (void) requestEWIServiceFinish:(EWIConnector *)connector responseData:(NSDictionary *)responseData{

    NSLog(@"finish %@",connector.serviceName);
    NSLog(@"response %@",responseData);

    if ([connector.serviceName isEqualToString:@"special_selected_f10"])
    {
        NSLog(@"finish %@",connector.serviceName);
        NSDictionary *content = responseData[@"content"];
        NSString *stAlertMes = [content objectForKey:@"alertMessage"];
        stAlertMes = [self getString:stAlertMes];
        NSLog(@"AlertMSG : %@", stAlertMes);
        if (![stAlertMes isEqualToString:@""]) {
            NSLog(@"ALERT MESSAGE : %@", stAlertMes);
            gloablOnWherehouse.arTableDataSelected = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"HAS DATA");
            gloablOnWherehouse.arTableDataSelected = [content objectForKey:@"DataList_SPI_DetailCollection"];
            [self.tableViewWhereHoseList reloadData];

            labelStatus.text = @"F11";

        }
    }
 else
    {
        NSLog(@"response %@",responseData);
    }


}

- (void) requestEWIServiceFail:(EWIConnector *)connector error:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"request fail %@",connector);
}


- (NSString *)getString:(NSString *)string
{
    return [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}


- (IBAction)btnf10
{
    NSMutableDictionary *content = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [content setValue:[[AppSetting sharedInstance] token] forKey:@"ewitoken"];
    //[content setValue:gloablOnWherehouse.selectedWhereHouse forKey:@"model_Name"];
    [[EWIConnector connector] requestEWIService:@"special_selected_f10" requestData:content delegate:self];
}
```

**UITableView2**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    globlOnDisplayEffect = [GlobalVariable sharedInstance];
    globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelectedWhereHouse = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    [self.tableViewDetailList reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return (globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected)?[globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected count]: 1;
}



- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"DisplayEffectQtyViewCell";
    DisplayEffectQtyViewCell *cell = [self.tableViewDetailList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DisplayEffectQtyViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    } else {
        if (globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected) {
            NSMutableArray *myMutbleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [myMutbleArray addObject:globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected];

            if (myMutbleArray) {
                NSDictionary *myDic = [globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                NSDictionary *cont = [myDic objectForKey:@"DataList_SPI_DetailF10"];
                NSString *f10_cmpt = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_cmpt"]];
                NSString *f10_dt = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_dt"]];
                NSString *f10_item = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_item"]];
                NSString *f10_lot = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_lot"]];
                NSString *f10_model = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_model"]];
                NSString *f10_of = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_of"]];
                NSString *f10_semi = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_semi"]];
                NSString *f10_tm = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_tm"]];
                NSString *f10_uncmp = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_uncmp"]];

                [cell setf10_cmpt:f10_cmpt setf10_dt:f10_dt setf10_item:f10_item setf10_lot:f10_lot setf10_model:f10_model setf10_of:f10_of setf10_semi:f10_semi setf10_tm:f10_tm setf10_uncmp:f10_uncmp];


            }
        }
    }
    return cell;

}

- (void) requestEWIServiceStart:(EWIConnector *)connector{

    NSLog(@"start %@",connector.endpoint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TO Check if view controller already push or not.

```
 if(![self.navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[NewViewController class]]) {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
  }
```